# using do visual studio unnecessary

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Alguém sabe por que fica assim?

[image: Imagem]

Fica apresentando que a using não está sendo usada, mas não entendo pq não é reconhecida se eu estou usando na função mais abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resolução:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
    using System.Data;

    namespace MySqlServerDemo
    {
    public partial class WebForm1 : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindData();
        }

       public void BindData()
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user    id=root;database=test");
            con.Open();

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from person", con);
            MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds);

            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: qual função do using você esta usando?

Comment: Esses alertas aparecem porque não é uma boa prática manter a chamada de bibliotecas que você não está utilizando neste escopo.  Na declaração de sua classe ao herdar as informações da classe *Page*, não existe a necessidade de informar todo o namespace ali, você pode apenas deixar o nome da classe como no exemplo a baixo.

`public partial class WebForm1 : Page`

Uma maneira de corrigir estes alertas é clicar com o botão direito sobre o item destacado e utilizar a função *Organize Usings -> Remove Unecessary Usings* ou então utilizar o atalho *CTRL + .*

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza conectar o banco de daods mysql

Comment: @LeandroAraujo Fiz o que disse e habilitou apenas uma using, eu preciso habilitar todas, comecei a usar o visual studio agora, por isso estou com essas dúvidas bobas.

Comment: se você remover o Mysql.Data.MysqlClient da erro?

Comment: fica com os mesmos erros

Comment: você que dizer ( não esta sendo utilizado) para mim isso não é erro.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza olhe a imagem que postei agora, fica com aqueles erros por que a using Mysql.Data.MysqlClient esta "desabilitado"

Comment: Não é isso, seu sistema esta com erro.. o que dar para ver de cara é a declaração do método BinData , você esqueceu os () no final. o certo seria  `public void BindData() { ..... }`, edite sua pergunta com o código em se no lugar da imagem para que fique mais legível.

Comment: Ok, vou fazer isso, obrigada!

Comment: @Lorena me parece que a declaração da sua função BindData está incorreta, tente o seguinte

`public void BindData()`

Comment: @Lorena se alterar a linha
`MySqlCommand =cmd = new MySqlCommand()` Para 
`MySqlComman cmd = new MySqlComman()` Creio que irá funcionar, e o mesmo para `MySqlAdapter`

Comment: @RenanCarlos fui me dar conta disso depois, já arrumei, muito obrigada!

Comment: Resolvido! Muito obrigada pessoal. @MarconcilioSouza

Comment: @RenanCarlos valeu!

Comment: @LeandroAraujo valeu!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O seu problema esta ocorrendo devido a criação incorreta do método `BindData`, na finalização do seu método você esqueceu os ().

Veja a declaração correta.

```
public void BindData() 
{ 
     // seu código ... 
}
```

Compile (clique no botão [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] Build Solution) seu projeto e corrija todos os erros que apareçam, após isso as referencias que não forem realmente utilizadas ficarão em cor mais claras (quase transparentes) essas referencias podem ser removidas sem problemas para a aplicação, você pode remover por conta uma a uma ou utilizar o botão ([image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]) para remover todas as reverencias não utilizadas e ordenar as que ficarem.

Answer (score 1):

Bem, em complemento a resposta do @MarconcilioSouza, existe mais erros no seu código.

Repare nestas linha:

```
MySqlCommand = cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from person", con);
MySqlDataAdapter = adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

A declaração correta é:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from person", con);
MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

Ou seja, seu método `BindData` deverá ficar assim:

```
public void BindData()
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user    id=root;database=test");
    con.Open();

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from person", con);
    MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds);

    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Close();
 }
```

Feito essas modificações, acredito que funcionará normalmente. 
Caso tenha outras dúvidas estou a disposição, no que puder ajudar.

Comment: Certo @RenanCarlos, muito obrigada pela ajuda, já está tudo certo!

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta, os "usings" mais claros ***teoricamente*** não estão sendo usados e podem ser removidos.

*Teoricamente* porque caso haja um erro de sintaxe, o pré-compilador do VS pode marcar uma determinada linha de *using* como não necessária quando ela de verdade é (após correção da sintaxe).

É uma boa prática remover as linhas excedentes para manter o código mais limpo.

Comment: Ok @FabricioGS, fiz isso e está tudo correndo bem, muito obrigada!